# Need to replace character but .replace not helping

Tags: javascript, math

Alright, so I have some javascript and basically it gets a math equation from a website, changes it up so that it is readable by `eval()` and then puts it through eval, then when I press a key it inserts the answer from `eval()` into the inputBox. I have a question that is, (for example) y + ? = 20. The "y" changes from the numbers 1-20. So far, The code gets the answer to the question, but in negative form. (example: 14 + ? = 20 = -14). So I need help removing all "-" characters from my answer.

Code variables:

```
var inputBox = where the answer is (like -14 in my case)    
var question = the question. in my case 14 + ? = 20
```

The code so far:

```
//Mathletics Level 4 with Blocks//
function showAnswer(){

var inputBox = document.getElementsByClassName("questions-input-adjustment questions-input-width-v3")[0];
var submitButton = document.getElementsByClassName('question-input-form')[0];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   var question = document.getElementsByClassName("questions-text-alignment whiteTextWithShadow question-size-v4")[0].innerText;
   question = question.replace('= 20', '-20')
   question = question.replace('×', '*')
   question = question.replace('=', '');
   question = question.replace('=', '');
   var answer = eval(question)
   inputBox.value = answer;

 var awnser = addbits(equasion)

var inputBox = document.getElementsByClassName("questions-input-adjustment questions-input-width-v3")[0];
var submitButton = document.getElementsByClassName('question-input-form')[0];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   var question = document.getElementsByClassName("questions-text-alignment")[0].innerText;
   question = question.replace('= 20', '-20')
   question = question.replace(' =', '');
   question = question.replace('×', '*')
   question = question.replace('=', '');
   inputBox.value = answer;

}

 var awnser = addbits(equasion)

document.getElementById('dashow').innerText = awnser;
 document.getElementsByClassName("questions-input-adjustment questions-input-width-v3")["0"].value = awnser;
}

 window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == "81") {
       showAnswer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
myanswer= myanswer.replace(/-/g,'');
```

it reomve the minus from the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can remove minus by using below abs function

```js
          a =-3
          x=Math.abs(a);
          console.log(x)
```